# ERROR: operator does not exist: date >= character varying

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have this problem:

this query in PostgreSQL PG Admin work fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM raport_das 
where cast(raport_das.dataZawarcia as date) >= '2017-09-04%' 
  and cast(raport_das.dataZawarcia as date) <= '2018-09-04%' 
  and raport_das.status = 'umowa'

SELECT * 
FROM raport_das 
where raport_das.dataZawarcia >= '2017-09-04' 
  and raport_das.dataZawarcia <= '2018-09-04' 
  and raport_das.status = 'umowa'
```

but in spring-boot with hibernate and this method:

```
String REPORT_BY_DATE_STATUS = "SELECT * FROM raport_das where raport_das.dataZawarcia >= ?1 and raport_das.dataZawarcia <= ?2 and raport_das.status = ?3";

@Async
    @Query(value = REPORT_BY_DATE_STATUS, nativeQuery = true)
    List<RaportDas> findByDateAndStatus(String dateFrom, String dateTo, String status);
```

I have this ERROR:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: date >= character varying.
>   No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

My entity uses `java.util.Date`. But I tried with sql.date as well, but gives the same error.

Comment: Don't pass the parameters as Strings, declare them as Date: `findByDateAndStatus(java.sql.Date dateFrom, java.sql.Date dateTo, String status);`

Comment: thanks for answer, but for MySQL every thing forks fine.

Comment: That's because MySQL doesn't really care about proper data types. Would you try to pass a `String` to a function in Java that expects a `Date` parameter and assume that the compiler just does the right thing?

Comment: It worked in pgAdmin because it was `unknown` type and Postgres guessed what it could be. When you give explicit type, then it doesn't do that anymore. You could still create implicit cast, but I would just follow advice from a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: @łukaszdusza hey, did you get this type cast ERROR when using  actual string date inputs or when you input  NULL? can you please respond

Comment: if you really need to use String instead of Date for some important reason, you can cast `raport_das.dataZawarcia` to String and compare strings. Date formatted with `yyyy-MM-dd` is sorted in the same order as regular Date. I don't recommend this way, but sometimes it might help